# Button not firing function ajax jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an **index.php** where the user can reserve a lot. the button is from the other page **2dmap_func.php** which then displayed inside the id "detalye" in index.php after ajax call was executed.

> index.php

```
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#reserve').click(function(){
  alert('ok');

});

var lnk2; 
var lot
    $('[href]').click(function(){
        lnk2 = ''; 
        lot='';
           lnk2 = $(this).attr('href');
           if (lnk2.charAt(1) == "b") {
              lot = lnk2;
              $.ajax({
                url: "2dmap_func.php",
                method: "POST",
                dataType: "text",
                data: {lot:lot},
                success: function(data) {
                   $('#detalye').html(data);
                }
              });
            }
      });
});
</script>
```

> 2dmap_func.php

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM lots WHERE link='$_POST[lot]'";  
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

 $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE lot='$_POST[lot]'";  
$result1 = $conn->query($sql2);

echo '<div id="head_d">LOT DETAILS</div>
<div id="content_d">
<div id="location"><h3>Block:</h3> '.$row['block'].' &bull;&nbsp; <h3>Lot:</h3> '.$row['lot'].'</div>
<div id="type">Type: '.$row['type'].'</div>
<div id="dimensions">North: '.$row['dimension_north'].'&bull;&nbsp;East: '.$row['dimension_east'].'&bull;&nbsp;West: '.$row['dimension_west'].'&bull;&nbsp;South: '.$row['dimension_south'].'</div>
<div id="button">'.(($result1->num_rows < 1) ?'<button id="reserve">Reserve this Lot</button>':'This lot is currently not available for Reservation.').'</div>
</div>';
```

Comment: strikes me as odd to try and use an attribute selector without the tag /id/or class to go with it.  I also dont see any tags with an href attribute in `2dmap_func.php` or `index.php`

Comment: You need to use a delegated event handler as the `#reserve` element does not exist in the DOM when the page loads. See the question I marked as duplicate for more information